# Trouble with implementing ChatGPT functions, no function response

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have started today with the new chatGPT functions and made it work with the basic example, However, when I try to make my own example I never get the function response, but just the basic role and content properties.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I formulating it wrong? The idea is to hold a conversation with a person. I want two properties, a response property and a translation property that translates the response into English (eventually I want to add more properties, but I can't even make it work with two)

```
const createConversation = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let messages = [{ role: "user", content: "Hola" }];
    const functions = [
      {
        name: "get_response_in_spanish",
        description:
          "Continue the conversation that takes place in a restaurant in Spanish",
        parameters: {
          type: "object",
          properties: {
            response: {
              type: "string",
              description: "a response in Spanish",
            },
            translation: {
              type: "string",
              description: "a translation of the response in English",
            },
          },
          required: ["response"],
        },
      },
    ];
    const completion = await communicateWithOpenAI(model, messages, functions);
    console.log("TEST", completion.data.choices[0]);
    return res.status(200).json({ savedConversation: "hey" });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the creation of the meal
    console.error("error", error.message);
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "An Error occured while getting a chat" });
  }
};

async function communicateWithOpenAI(model, messages, functions) {
  const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "some-key",
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  });
  const mappedMessages = messages.map((message) => {
    const { role, content } = message;
    return {
      role,
      content,
    };
  });
  const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
  const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
    temperature: 0.7,
    messages: mappedMessages,
    functions,
    function_call: "auto",
  });
  return completion;
}
```

Response I get, without function result:

[image]